# Stick text element to right of div

Tags: html, css

I've got a menu of items that need to be displayed with their prices in the following manner:

`ITEM...................120`

(The dots are just to show the spacing between the two and will not appear in the code)

What I've done till now is create a `div` of `width:200px` in which I've put the text.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/jE2YL/1/

However, I'd like to know if it's possible to stick the price to the right margin of the box?
I've tried `padding-left: X px;`, but I've got a list of 100+ menu items each of which have arbitrary length of characters which in turn changes the padding for each price element and changing the padding of each element is rather cumbersome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `position: absolute` and `position: relative`.

Use the following CSS:

```
.abc{
    width:200px;
    background:#ccc;
}
    .abc h5 {
        position: relative;
    }
        .abc h5 span {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
        }
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/jE2YL/2/)

Alternatively, you can just use `float: right` on the `<span>`:

```
.abc h5 span {
    float: right
}
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo 2**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/jE2YL/3/)